# TFS+VS2008, Error code 50

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, tfs, compiler-errors

I have an error whenever I try to perform a "get specific version" and mark the "Overwrite" options.

The message is:

```
 [path to my local file]  Method failed  with unexpected error code 50.
```

no further details were provided, and I didnt find the error code in the Microsoft documentation, the error only appear when I mark both of the overwrite options.

Any clue about why this  error appear, how to avoid it, a work around, or a link  with usefull information will be apreciated.